# how can i create a local copy of grails repository

Tags: grails, repository, clone, local

Hi i ll like to create a working copy of grails plugin repository. This is not a git or svn repo.

http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/#

I install Artifactfactory but it don't have that option.
Any help is appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a maven repo, you can setup a proxy in artifactory by folliwng the docs here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Repositories